# Showing Dialog from Android Application Object (or need routine available to multiple activities)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Fragments are NOT essential to my question (so don't leave lol), but I mention it to explain why I am trying to do this.

I am using fragments so depending on layout a different activity will be the container.  Because of that I need this routine available to multiple activities.  I have a common routine that needs to run regardless of which activity is used and so in order to not duplicate code I set up the routine to run from the application object.

This code works if it is contained in the activity, but when put in the application object (and modified as necessary) it fails.  When I attempt to .show() the dialog I get the error "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application".

This is the calling routine from one of the activities that needs to call the failing routine:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, ChecklistListActivity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.mnuDelete:
            ((KnowUrStuffApp)getApplication()).deleteChecklist(this);//<--This is the call!!!
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

This is the routine contained in my application subclass:

```
public void deleteChecklist(final FragmentActivity sender){
    Checklist cl = getDbHelper().getCurrentChecklist();
    if (cl == null)
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.strSelectAChecklistToDelete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else {
        try {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setMessage(cl.getChecklistTitle() + " " + getString(R.string.strConfirmDelete))
               .setCancelable(true)
               .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                          performDeleteChecklist();
                          if (sender instanceof ChecklistDetailActivity)
                              NavUtils.navigateUpTo(sender, new Intent(sender, ChecklistListActivity.class));
                      }
                  })
               .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
               .show();//<--This causes exception!

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG * 4).show();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work, or if this is a total wrong way to have this routine available to multiple activities, how could I make it available?

I could duplicate the code in each activity to make it work, but then I'll have to remember to update both whenever I make changes.  Further I will need several more routines that I will need to do the same thing for so I really need to figure out how to make my routine available to multiple activities.

Thank you guys so much! :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  Change this line:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

to:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(sender)
```

Comment: Yep that's it. Thank you Kaedil. Thanks also to kcoppock who told me the same in chat. :-)  I have a couple more minutes before I can accept it, but I shall return ;-)